# update new records in a php page from SQL without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I usually do android app dev and i have no idea about php. I have this php page(created using php maker) which displays a record from my MySQL database. I have to refresh the page every time or keep it to reload every 'x' seconds to see new records from my DB. How can i set that certain page to update the records without reloading the page using jQuery every 'x' second.

Answer (score 1):

**First**

You will need to put your php in a seperate file and echo the data back, something like this.

**myfile.php**

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = '$id'";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        echo $row['something'];
    }
?>
```

Use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) in jquery to make a call to that php file every x seconds, in this case 5 seconds.

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    setInterval( function () {
        $('#someidtoloadto').load('/path/to/myfile.php');
    }, 5000); // loads every 5 seconds
});
```

Then have a `div` or whatever you want the data to be rendered too.

**html**

```
<div id="someidtoloadto"></div>
```

Comment: no .. since i use php maker to auto generate the code.. its too complicated. I need to add this in the php script itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery ajax function to send request after every 'x' seconds to update the page and update the fetched data on the page.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "update.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {id : id},
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        $("#results").append(html);
    }
});
```